# zip file creation, forward slash is present in filename. so zip file is not creating instead of showing 404 error using php

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

While creating a zip file, in filename forward slash(/) is present. So the zip file is not creating in PHP. It getting 404 error

My code is:

```
$filename= "Test/case1";
$zip_file=$filename.date("Y-m-d-h-i-s").'.zip';
```

Comment: use underscore(_) instead of forward slash(/)

Comment: Already $filename is present, so i need to create zipfile without removing forward slash.

Comment: If you already have then use str_replace("/", "_", $filename) and remove slash as it won't allow you to create a filename

Comment: @pravindot17 Could you please clarify the doubt. In $filename if the forward slash is present means it will not allow to create a zip file?

Comment: as it may consider that Test is your folder name and if it doesn't exists it won't create your zip file will throw error

Comment: @pravindot17 I actually tried by using forward slash in filename, but it is not creating. when i tried using hypen. the zip file is creating.

Comment: hope your problem is resolved

Comment: @pravindot17 But i can't use hyphen. Because most of the filename is by using forward slash. So i need to include it when exporting.

Comment: Could you please help me to get the solution.

Comment: You need to check other way of naming filenames, as most of the os doesn't allowed slash in filenames